# CGContextFillEllipseInRect draw dots more than 1000 stuck the app

Tags: ios, iphone

i have created 1000+ dots using CGContextFillEllipseInRect it will stop the the application and when drawing completed, app run smoothly any option for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `CALayer`'s `drawsAsynchronously` property and set it to **`YES`** for view in which you draw - this will send drawing commands to background thread and your main queue should be intact and interface should stay responsive.

**UPDATE**: From question itself not very clear where you draw those points, but I assume what it happens from `-drawInRect:. At any moment, when your view will load, you need to configure`CALayer` like this:

```
self.layer.drawsAsynchronously = YES;
```

If view in which you draw visible in Interface Builder, you can specify `drawsAsynchronously` from IB using *Identity Inspector* (Option+CMD+3). Find section of *User Defined Runtime Attributes* add there `layer.drawsAsynchronousl` key with **Boolean** type checked.

Comment: Can you show one example or reference url for the code flow